# Unable to successfully use custom mapped vim commands from vimrc (mac)

Tags: vim

I am trying to add a command to my `.vimrc` and use it.

I have recorded a macro (in the register `h`) that prints the following (ending with a newline):

```
one
two
three
```

I can see this in the register `h` by typing `:reg`. It looks like:

```
"h   ione^Mtwo^Mthree^M^[
```

I've pasted this as well as an alternate version in my `.vimrc` under `test` and `test2` respectively:

```
map <Leader>test ione^Mtwo^Mthree^M^[
map <Leader>test2 ione<C-R>two<C-R>three<C-R><ESC>
```

My understanding is that `test` uses characters that can't be displayed such as `^M` and `^[`, so I've created `test2` with what I've read is the `.vimrc` equivalent.

After restarting vim (which I assume means starting another vim session after this `.vimrc` has been written to), I test these out.

In normal mode (after hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd> multiple times), I try **both** of the following:

`:test`

`:test2`

In both cases, I'm given the error for each respectively:

`E492: Not an editor command: test`

`E492: Not an editor command: test2`

After no avail, I check to see if what I've mapped has been mapped.
In normal mode, I type `:map` and do indeed see what I've added, but they appear with a backslash:

```
   \test2        ione<C-R>two<C-R>three<C-R><Esc>
   \test         ione^Mtwo^Mthree^M^[
```

Finally, in normal mode, I try again, this time with a backslash. I try **both** of the following:

`:\test`

`:\test2`

This time, I receive the following error for **both** commands:

```
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
```

I am on a mac and have tried using both Terminal (which comes with OSX) as well as iTerm2.

Could someone please lend me some guidance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your mappings are executed if you press your leader key followed by the keys `test` or `test2`. You did not create commands (`:`).

If you want them as command, then you don't need a mapping, but something along the lines of this in your `.vimrc`:

```
function! Test()                
    execute "normal ione"      
    execute "normal otwo"      
    execute "normal othree"    
    execute "normal o"         
endfunc                        
command -nargs=0 Test call Test()
```

Which you can then use as `:Test`.

However, if you want to make a mapping and not a command, you might want:

- a shorter mapping to type (this is very subjective),
- to use `nnoremap` instead of `map` (To be usable in normal mode only, and to not recursively execute mappings),
- your `test2` is what you need (that I change here into `<leader>t`)
- `<C-R>` is `Control R`, you want `<CR>` for the return key.

Here's an example:

```
nnoremap <Leader>t ione<CR>two<CR>three<CR><ESC>
```